# Generating EXE file for a java application

Tags: java, mysql, exe, executable, executable-jar

I have developed a stand alone Java Application which contains the following.

1. MySQL Installation
2. Java Application code
3. Tables and stored procedures
4. Batch files
5. VB Script files

I am planning to generate an Executable file which allows the user to install all the above with a single click. I am able to generate a Jar file but not an Exe file.

Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you trying to make an executable jar, or are you trying to make an installer?

Comment: I am planning make an installer. Not Jar.

Comment: Besides being a duplicate, you haven't explained what you've tried so far. SO isn't a place to request free tutorials, so this question should be rejected even if it isn't a duplicate. This said, simply adding what you've tried so far and *exactly* what the issue is would be acceptable, if it wasn't a duplicate.